# LED panel refresh rate and scan rate (multiplexing) relationship

Tags: led-matrix

Considering high-end panel as ROE Ruby 2.3 https://www.roevisual.nl/uploads/bestanden/ruby-r2.3-brochure-lr-v12020.pdf the scan rate (multiplexing) is \$s=1/12\$ and refresh rate is \$f=1920\$ Hz.

What does the refresh rate mean? Does it mean how many times per second are \$1/12\$ od LEDs illuminated, or the whole display? Meaning that scan refresh rate would be \$f_{scan} = \frac{f}{s} = 23.040 \$ KHz?

Or is it that refresh rate means \$f_{scan}\$ and actual whole display refresh rate is \$f = f_{scan} \times s = 160\$Hz?

Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: A proper data sheet is required.

Comment: @Andyaka I'd probably be able to answer it for myself if I had one. I'm totally find with someone providing an expectation on how it should be based on his/her experience with other panels.

Comment: You might be disappointed.